# Why this program is crashing did i wrongly allocated memory

Tags: c

This program is crashing. Please tell me what's wrong with it. When I use an array instead of a pointer like `Name[12]` in the structure it doesn't crash. I guess there is some problem in dynamic memory allocation. Help please.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct struct_tag
{
    int number;
    char *Name;
} struct_name;


main()
{
    struct_name.number = 34;

    char *Name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
    strcpy(struct_name.Name,"A");

    printf("%d", struct_name.number);
}
```

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: `char *Name` is not the same as `struct_name.Name`.

Comment: @unwind sir my teacher told me malloc return void pointer its important to cast it tell what should the return value

Comment: @StackOverflow Then I don't agree with your teacher. :) Consider showing the linked-to answer. Casting `void *` to a different pointer type in C is pointless; it's not needed and it can hide actual errors, all the while making the code harder to read. Don't do it.

Comment: @unwind can you give me an example when it can hide errors & why it is pointless refer me to some question or text that i can read & understand your point of pointless casting...Thanks

Comment: @unwind got it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc ........just googled why not to cast malloc. Thanks

Comment: @StackOverflow You googled, to find the link I gave you when I first said something about casting? Full circle! :)

Comment: @unwind sorry i somehow didn't saw that comment. Something is really wrong today. My mind is not working the way it show be :( Thanks anyways having people like you around is no more than blessing for Noobs & leaners like me.

Comment: & the best thing is you answered it there. However i can't thumbs up your answer :( coz of low reputation...so well explained

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're allocating a single character:

```
char *Name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
```

And then never using that memory for anything.  You meant to allocate memory for `struct_name.Name`, undoubtedly. But even if you had done so, you're then filling it with *two* characters (`'a'` and `'\0'`):

```
strcpy(struct_name.Name,"A");
```

which will cause an entirely different bug.

You *want* to say:

```
struct_name.Name = malloc( 2 );
```

Since (a) you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` and (b) `sizeof(char)` is always `1` and (c) you need room for the `0` at the end of your string.

Answer (score 2):

For errors:

- You are allocating memeory for `*Name` however you are not allocating
  memory for `struct_name.Name`. So first thing is you need to allocate memory for `struct_name.Name`
- As you already know that you'll be storing `"A"` in
  `struct_name.Name` you should allocate memory for 2 char.(`"A"` is string i.e 'A' and '\0')

For warnings:

- If you want to use `strcpy` function include `string.h` in your code.
- Also if you are using `malloc` include `stdlib.h` in your code.

Try this fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct struct_tag
{
    int number;
    char *Name;
}struct_name;

int main()
{
    struct_name.number = 34;
    struct_name.Name = malloc(sizeof(char)*2); // As you will store "A" 
    strcpy(struct_name.Name,"A");

    printf("%d \t", struct_name.number);
    printf("%s \n", struct_name.Name);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP asked "Please tell me whats wrong with this program".

Comment: @Jongware: I have also removed all the warning from OP's code. Please explain why you downvote my answer?

Comment: "Try this", followed by just a piece of code with minimal commenting (only one single comment). Compare the other answers, which *explain* what the OP did wrong, and where, and what it should be.

Answer (score 1):

first look  code carefully.

```
 char *Name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
 strcpy(struct_name.Name,"A");
```

Hare for what you allocated memory (`char *Name`) and in which you copied string(`struct_name.Name`)?

here you not allocate memory for `struct_name.Name`. Also you have allocate memory for one character and you tried to copy two characters.('A' and '\0').

It should be

```
struct_name.Name = malloc(2);
```